# Stampede protection for Symfony Cache 5.4 using Generic Caching?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using [Symfony Cache](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/components/cache.html#stampede-prevention). Specifically the 5.4 version.

The documentation clearly specifies, for Cache Contracts:

> The Cache Contracts also come with built in Stampede prevention.

Thus Cache Contracts have Stampede prevention by default.

However, for various reasons I want to use [Generic Caching](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/components/cache.html#generic-caching-psr-6) based on PSR-6.

The documentation doesn't mention anything about stampede protection for Generic Caching, so I can assume that it doesn't have any(or maybe it does and I don't know about it?)

What are my options to have stampede prevention with generic caching specifically with Symfony?